# puzzling.stackexchange.com turns left monitor black

Tags: ubuntu, display, multiple-monitors

This is a weird one.

This is a new issue on an existing Ubuntu 14.04, dual screen setup, using Unity, nothing out of the ordinary. When I go to [puzzling.stackexchange.com](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com) on my *left* monitor screen in either chrome or firefox, that screen turns black.

**This does not happen on any other website**, but does happen on every page on that site (that I've tried). Going to that site in a browser on my right monitor screen doesn't have that effect. If I drag the browser from the right monitor onto the left one, the left monitor turns black once I've gotten it mostly over there. It starts showing stuff again when I drag it back.

My left screen (the one with the problem) is using an HDMI cable and the other screen is using a DVI cable. The problem persists across rebooting.

Puzzling SE recently got a new site design, [documented here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4630/puzzling-design-pitch-congratulations-youre-graduating). What could be going on?

Running `lshw -c video` gives:

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Curacao XT [Radeon R7 370 / R9 270X/370 OEM]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:63 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f7e00000-f7e3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7e40000-f7e5ffff
```

Comment: Hmm, this is quite puzzling.

Comment: Try loading the page with JavaScript disabled.